# Looking for an initial web application generator like JHipster but with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase-authentication

I'm looking for a tool what I can use for generate an initial web application.

Previously I used [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech) for my Applications, which uses Java Spring on server side, but currently I don't want to maintain a Spring backend only a NodeJs.

Requirements:

- using Angular as frontend
- using NodeJS as backend
- using Firebase for (authentication, collection and data storage)
- pre built Authentication mechanism (including user register and login)

Do you have any suggestion?
Or how can I speed up these initial steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-nodejs it **does not** use Firebase

Comment: At first look, this is exactly what I need. I will check it out. Thank you!